# A good way to create an "appearing content" effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm in need of an effect, where certain div's in website fade-in when the page is opened (so they will be fading from 0 to 100 opacity).

I've created this effect with js but I'm not sure if this is the best way to go with. I would love to get some thoughts on getting a good way to create a similar effect.

For some reason I believe this can be done with pure css3, what do you think?

Comment: Can you please post a jsfiddle with what you have so far?

Comment: It is simple jquery fade in right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain CSS will work:

```
@keyframes fadein {from{opacity:0} to{opacity:1}}
@keyframes fadeout {from{opacity:1} to{opacity:0}}
```

Then you can use `animation: fadein 1s linear` (or whatever) on the elements you want to make fade in.

Comment: IMO `transition: opacity 1s linear` is more convenience than `keyframes`.

Comment: Except `transition` requires something change it, `animation` applies to the element immediately without external interference.

Comment: But `keyframes` happens as the stylesheet is loaded which is before the DOM is loaded and the animation might not be visible. (is it?)

Comment: Oh this is it! Simple, effective.

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery's .fadeIn('') function.

Comment: So you take the lazy and inefficient option.

Comment: So does mine, except mine works about a million times more efficiently ;)

Comment: It works on the browsers used by 62% of global internet users. 62% > 50%, therefore "most" is true :p

Comment: That would be the reason why I'd have to choose the jQuery method, even if it's 1000 times less efficient. Number one rule of programming - it needs to work.

Comment: My number one rule is that if people can't be arsed to update, why should I be arsed to downgrade?